# mysql restore and overwrite

Tags: mysql, restore, overwrite

I have a backup of my entire host 11 DB and some tables. I messed some stuff up and I want to restore and while restoring OVERWRITE.

`mysql -u root -p < plasesavetheday.sql`

I get errors about database existing and Duplicate entry '11' for key 'id'.
how can I tell the import or edit the file to be an overwtire.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like your dump file has a `CREATE DATABASE` in it. If so, you should drop the database before you load the dump file:

```
$ mysqladmin -u root -p drop database
```

Now you can load the dump file:

```
$ mysql -u root -p < plasesavetheday.sql
```

Of course, you might want to backup the database first, just in case!